# Suggestion to provide [kbd:] markup to simplify <kbd></kbd>

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, kbd

Obviously, this is not a big deal, but typing `<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>` to get <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> is a little tedious, and those who need to use it could save a few keystrokes with `[kbd:F][kbd:o][kbd:o]` if it is supported. This is similar to the `[tag:tag]` syntax for [tag](/questions/tagged/tag).

Comment: Why not `[kbd:Foo]`? If you want a key to consist of several character, maybe they can be enclosed in quotes: `[kbd:'ctrl']`. Just throwing ideas around...

Comment: @Felix - That's depend on us. We can write both (`<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>` and `<kbd>Foo</kbd>`) at present.

Comment: I just noticed that my suggestion is not really that useful :D  I think use cases where someone needs *continues* key formatting is quite rare. Often you'd put `+`s between them to indicate keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Felix Well that sounds like a good idea. I mean, putting the key sequence in quotes, when you need it as a single key. Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [this script](https://stackapps.com/q/3341/10098) to make kbd-ifying easier.

This really isn't that necessary. Besides being another change to the already abused MarkDown, it isn't as intuitive to newbies. Also, it takes about the same amount of time for me to type, so there's not much gain in this , imho:/

Comment: How does it take the same amount of time to type? You can skip the closing tag </kbd>, that's 5 keystrokes in exchange for an extra colon (:), so overall saves 4 keystrokes.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai: _about_ the same. Maybe a second's worth of difference.

Comment: I wish they could somehow magically give us auto tag closing, that would make this less painful.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like that it introduces new syntax completely different than the other syntax in markdown, while being nearly as tedious to type...

Comment: It isn't new. It is similar to `[tag:]` syntax.

Comment: Right, it is similar to [tag:], and that's indeed where I got the idea from.

Comment: But `[tag:]` is kind-of a link, which matches the `[]`-indicates-a-link idea found in ... well, links. `<kbd>` is not a kind of a link at all.